# Understanding the meaning of the notation $([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)$

Tags: notation

When learning about tagged partitions I'm introduced to the notation $([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)$. Is this referring to all numbers y such that $x_{i-1}<y<t_i$ ? Or does it mean something else? Cheers

Comment: Some more context might be helpful here, but I *suspect* that you're studying Riemann sums, and in this context, $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ is one of the intervals in your partition, and $t_i$ is a point in this interval at which the function is sampled. So, if you were to form a Riemann sum over a tagged partition containing this pair, then one of the sum terms would be $f(t_i) \cdot (x_i - x_{i-1})$.

Comment: It is literally an ordered pair, where the first coordinate is the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ and the second coordinate is the number $t_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a partition of the intervall $[a,b]$, then put $I_i:=[x_{i-1},x_i], \quad (i=1,...,n) $.

Then $([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)$ means that $t_i \in I_i.$